# why \r\n displayed as ^M in vi?

Tags: vim, vi

I uploaded a windows text file and I found there are a bunch of ^M displayed. I think it is new line char, but I am wondering why ^M get displayed get displayed in this case?

Comment: For this I would use the tool `dos2unix`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^M` is the control-character representation of `\r` (carriage return is ASCII 13 in decimal; M is the 13th letter of the alphabet); the `\n` is displayed implicitly, as usual, by a line break.

Answer (score 1):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format

When in text editor mode (`vi file.txt`) you can change the line endings using

```
:set ff=unix
```

You could be using a better text editor like Notepad++ or NetBeans which automatically use the unix line ending or at least have the ability to switch properly between them.